Paho Mqtt Android Client logging in Android Studio
I want to read all incoming and outgoing requests in my android application that communicates with mqtt. What should I do for this? The mqtt service I use is as follows
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.2.0'
I want to see all incoming and outgoing requests as json
I logged according to the answer to the question below, but this was not what I wanted. I want to be able to see responses and requests as json.
How to enable Paho Mqtt Android Client logging in Android Studio


Stack Overflow questions should include what you have tried, not just a list of requirement

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

hi @hardillb I updated my question. I would be very happy if you review it
